# How to compile Degrib on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: installation, linux

I'm trying to compile degrib on a typical Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server. However, I get an error "undefined reference to gzopen64" which appears to be common when compiling degrib. Do you have any suggestions?

I see Salda got it working at [How to convert GRIB-1 to GRIB-2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26391/how-to-convert-grib-1-to-grib-2). Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of `zlib` do you have installed and could you post more details from the error?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has zlib 1.2.3.4 installed but degrib source code comes with zlib 1.1.4.

The compilation error is shown at http://pastebin.com/SUsb2Gka

Comment: As stated in http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/NDFD_grib2Decoder/compile.php?os=unix , I think the answer is ... cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a zlib/ ... I'll need to confirm this.

Comment: Confirmed. Just had to make a copy of the system's libz.a into the zlib directory when compiling (make)

Comment: Could you add this as an "answer" (below) and mark that as "the answer". Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that the user solved, but didn't consider a proper answer (or didn't wish to publish an answer).

Comment: I got it to work by modifying my `src/degrib/Makefile` (after running `configure`) to replace all references to `../zlib/libz.a` with my system's installed zlib (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a`) and all references to `-L../zlib` (I left `-L../zlib/contrib/minizip` references alone) again with my system's installed zlib directory (`-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`). There were 4 places in the file that needed to change.